# ELK convert data stream back to regular index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I want to use regular index instead of datastream, but unable to delete/update it neither from Kibana UI nor with a help of direct ES api call

```
    "reason" : "composable template [logs_template] with index patterns [new-pattern*], priority [200] would cause data streams [logstash-2020.12.24] to no longer match a data stream template"
```

I cannot

- delete datastream or underlying index (it's got recreated)
- delete index template used to create data stream
- reassign index template to point to some dummy index and then delete the above (error below)

[image: error message kibana]

How can I migrate back to the regular index and discard data stream settings?

Kibana `v 7.9.2` / ES `7.9.2`

Comment: The same index template can be used for multiple data streams. You cannot delete an index template in use by a data stream. From docs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/data-streams.html

Answer (score 1):

I was able to delete data stream first and the corresponding index template by running ES/Kibana connection on different port.

```
# http.port: 9201
# /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
# /etc/kibana/kibana.yml
$ systemctl restart kibana
$ systemctl restart elasticsearch
```

This way datastream was not constantly recreated as nobody was writing to the new Elastic endpoint, so no issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same task.
I stoped `Logstash` to not allow to recreate datastream's indices.

```
sudo systemctl stop logstash
```

I removed datastreams and changed index templates to not use data streams.
After that I started `Logstash`.

```
sudo systemctl start logstash
```